# Check whether PHP incompatibility or MySqli incompatibility the issue?

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a site, built it and tested it on my own server. Now uploading to the client's server and every page with PHP/MySqli doesn't work. When the php/MySqli script appears in the page it just ends there, cutting out the rest of the content, footer etc.

Here is the version of the site on my server that works

http://progressivewebsolutions.ca/expmed/researchers.php

and here is the one on the clients server that doesnt work...

http://expmed.mcgill.ca/researchers.php

the client server is running php 5.2.6
    mysql 5.0.45

On the dbconnect file it is supposed to throw an error if it cannot connect and does not throw the error. Regardless of login info and password.

My question is what tools exist to check this issue and solve it? I taught myself to code and am constantly learning, just need a bit of guidance.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

I would look first in the web server's error log. Many PHP errors that are not output to the HTML are sent to the error log.

Make sure you have [PHP error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) enabled. See also [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

If you want more help, I suggest you edit your question above and show the code you use to connect to the MySQL instance.

Another strategy is to log into a shell on the PHP appserver host and try using the `mysql` command-line client to connect to the MySQL instance, using the same host, user, password that your PHP script uses.

```
$ mysql -h mysqlhost -u username -p
Enter password: <enter password here>
```

That will test if the hosts can talk to each other, and whether the login works (keep in mind MySQL connection privileges may be restricted by host, so one login that works from one appserver may not work from other appservers).

Comment: in phpmyadmin it says "Used PHP extensions: mysql" im assumign I need to try and enable mysqli? Is there a way to do this from phpmyadmin or would i need to contact clients server administrator?

Comment: I did the phpinfo thing and it says mysqli enabled any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome to try any of the ideas I already described, above.

Answer (score 0):

Start to perform a phpMyInfo in order to see if Mysqli is "on".

On the other way, under PHP, in such a case, the basic way of putting some "echo" along the code is, maybe, the best way.

After a look at the phpinfo(),it seems error reporting is off. So even if you have some errors, you cant' see them.

Just add:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

at the beginning of your page and maybe you'll see the errors.

Good luck!
Peter

Comment: could you expand on the phpmyinfo part? I looked on google and cannot find that...

Like I said, the first line in the php is a mysqliconnect and if it fails it echos an error. and not working. what would this show?

Comment: @user3404390 I believe he meant phpMyAdmin, which is a DB admin tool written in PHP. You should be able to run `phpinfo();` from either a PHP command prompt (`php -a` at the command line) or loaded as a web page and see whether the `mysqli` extension is enabled.

Comment: @John I did the phpinfo and it says mysqli is on. it can be seen at www.expmed.mcgill.ca/phpinfo.php